# Error when checking in files in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

In Visual Studio 2015, I have changed some version controlled files. When I right click the solution and select Check in nothing happens. In Output window, I can see this message:

> Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32.

What is the problem preventing me from checking in my files?

Note: My version control is cloud TFS built into the VS.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you have unsaved files and try to check them in.
Save all your files first, then try again.